# When popBackStack Fragment B -> Fragment A , which method is called in Fragment A?

Tags: android

First navigate view Fragment A -> Fragment B, and came back Fragment B -> Fragment A by `popBackStack.`

When `popBackStack` Fragment B -> Fragment A , which method is called in Fragment A ?

(in perspective of LifeCycle)

Comment: In Fragment A you can set logs at locations in the lifecycle (from `onCreate()` -> `onDestroy()`). Then you will get the desired result. :D Try it first.

Comment: @DươngMinh thanks! I'll try it.